# Callback in Linux kernel driver in order to hide device's low-level protocol

Tags: c, linux, callback, device-driver, kernel

I'm am writing a Linux kernel driver for HD44780 LCDs connected via I2C bus. In my last change I tried to decouple low-level code (which talks to the device via I2C) from device's logic (printing characters, parsing special characters, managing screen geometry etc.). I tried to solve it via a callback and it seems to work:

LCD data:

```
#define BUF_SIZE    64

struct hd44780_geometry {
    int cols;
    int rows;
    int start_addrs[];
};

struct hd44780 {
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct device *device;
    struct i2c_client *i2c_client;
    struct hd44780_geometry *geometry;
    int addr;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    struct {
        void (*f)(struct hd44780 *, int data);
        void *arg;
    } raw_callback;

    struct mutex lock;
    struct list_head list;
};

extern struct hd44780_geometry hd44780_geometry_20x4;

void hd44780_write(struct hd44780 *, char *, size_t);
void hd44780_init_lcd(struct hd44780 *);
void hd44780_print(struct hd44780 *, char *);
```

Initialization and callback code:

```
static void pcf8574_raw_write(struct hd44780 *lcd, int data)
{
    i2c_smbus_write_byte(lcd->raw_callback.arg, data);
}

static void hd44780_write_nibble(struct hd44780 *lcd, int data)
{
    pcf8574_raw_write(lcd, data);
    /* Theoretically wait for tAS = 40ns, practically it's already elapsed */

    pcf8574_raw_write(lcd, data | E);
    /* Again, "wait" for pwEH = 230ns */

    pcf8574_raw_write(lcd, data);
    /* And again, "wait" for about tCYC_E - pwEH = 270ns */
}

static int hd44780_file_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    filp->private_data = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct hd44780, cdev);
    return 0;
}

static int hd44780_file_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t hd44780_file_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp)
{
    struct hd44780 *lcd;
    size_t n;

    lcd = filp->private_data;
    n = min(count, (size_t)BUF_SIZE);

    // TODO: Consider using an interruptible lock
    mutex_lock(&lcd->lock);

    // TODO: Support partial writes during errors?
    if (copy_from_user(lcd->buf, buf, n))
        return -EFAULT;

    hd44780_write(lcd, lcd->buf, n);

    mutex_unlock(&lcd->lock);

    return n;
}

static void hd44780_init(struct hd44780 *lcd, struct hd44780_geometry *geometry,
        struct i2c_client *i2c_client)
{
    lcd->geometry = geometry;
    lcd->i2c_client = i2c_client;
    lcd->raw_callback.f = hd44780_write_nibble;
    lcd->raw_callback.arg = i2c_client;
    lcd->addr = 0x00;
    mutex_init(&lcd->lock); 
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .open = hd44780_file_open,
    .release = hd44780_file_release,
    .write = hd44780_file_write,
};

static int hd44780_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    dev_t devt;
    struct hd44780 *lcd;
    struct device *device;
    int ret, minor;

    minor = atomic_inc_return(&next_minor);
    devt = MKDEV(MAJOR(dev_no), minor);

    lcd = (struct hd44780 *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct hd44780), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!lcd) {
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    hd44780_init(lcd, &hd44780_geometry_20x4, client);

    spin_lock(&hd44780_list_lock);
    list_add(&lcd->list, &hd44780_list);
    spin_unlock(&hd44780_list_lock);

    cdev_init(&lcd->cdev, &fops);
    ret = cdev_add(&lcd->cdev, devt, 1);
    if (ret) {
        pr_warn("Can't add cdev\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    device = device_create(hd44780_class, NULL, devt, NULL, "lcd%d", MINOR(devt));
    if (IS_ERR(device)) {
        ret = PTR_ERR(device);
        pr_warn("Can't create device\n");
        goto del_exit;
    }
    lcd->device = device;

    hd44780_init_lcd(lcd);
    hd44780_print(lcd, "Hello, world!");

    return 0;

del_exit:
    cdev_del(&lcd->cdev);

    spin_lock(&hd44780_list_lock);
    list_del(&lcd->list);
    spin_unlock(&hd44780_list_lock);
exit:
    kfree(lcd);

    return ret;
}
```

And a piece of code that shows how the callback is called:

```
static void hd44780_write_nibble(struct hd44780 *lcd, int data) {
    lcd->raw_callback.f(lcd, data);
}

static void hd44780_write_command(struct hd44780 *lcd, int data)
{
    int h = (data >> 4) & 0x0F;
    int l = data & 0x0F;
    int cmd_h, cmd_l;

    cmd_h = (h << 4) | (RS & 0x00) | (RW & 0x00) | BL;
    hd44780_write_nibble(lcd, cmd_h);

    cmd_l = (l << 4) | (RS & 0x00) | (RW & 0x00) | BL;
    hd44780_write_nibble(lcd, cmd_l);

    udelay(37);
}
```

The crucial thing here is to pass the `i2c_client` to the `hd44780` struct so that the callback can use it later.

Is there a more pretty/recommended way to solve this problem?

You can find full source code [here](https://github.com/gorskima/hd44780-i2c/tree/cb12f86cb1d3599316e2b34ccbb853d9390081cd). This was originally asked [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/31896813/callback-in-linux-kernel-driver-in-order-to-hide-devices-low-level-protocol).

Answer (score 4):

### Pass arg instead of lcd

Right now, you are passing `lcd` to your callback function, but the callback function doesn't need `lcd`.  What it needs is the callback argument that you stored in `lcd->raw_callback.arg`.  I think you should pass that argument directly to the callback function, like this:

```
static void hd44780_write_nibble(struct hd44780 *lcd, int data)
{
    lcd->raw_callback.f(lcd->raw_callback.arg, data);
}
```

The callback function would look like this:

```
static void hd44780_write_nibble(void *arg, int data)
{
    pcf8574_raw_write(arg, data);
    /* Theoretically wait for tAS = 40ns, practically it's already elapsed */

    pcf8574_raw_write(arg, data | E);
    /* Again, "wait" for pwEH = 230ns */

    pcf8574_raw_write(arg, data);
    /* And again, "wait" for about tCYC_E - pwEH = 270ns */
}
```

And `pcf8574_raw_write()` would look like:

```
static void pcf8574_raw_write(void *arg, int data)
{
    i2c_smbus_write_byte(arg, data);
}
```

### Naming

I would rename `raw_callback` to `write_nibble_callback`.  I don't know what to expect when I call `raw_callback.f()`.

It's strange that you have two static functions both called `hd44780_write_nibble()`.  I realize that they are on two conceptually different layers of your program, but if I were debugging your program I would get confused as to which function I was in.

Comment: Good point with passing just the arg. But is the whole concept of this callback correct?

Comment: @m.g. The concept seems OK to me.  I've used callbacks like this before for similar reasons.